# Angular Facebook login in popup with 'code' instead of 'access_token'

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to use Facebook login in my application.

I want to login from the frontend (Angular 2) get the `code` and sent it to refresh my token from the API.

My code is:

```
//constructor
fb.init({appId: '234',xfbml: true,version: 'v2.8'});
//button clicked
this.fb.login({
    enable_profile_selector: true,
    return_scopes: true,
    scope: 'public_profile,user_friends,email,pages_show_list',
}).then((response: LoginResponse) => {}));
```

But it returns an `accessToken` instead of `code`.

How do I get `code` after login?

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think it is possible to get a `code` instead of `access_token` with the JS SDK - if you are using the official one, that is. Getting a code is possible with the manual login flow: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

**But: Refreshing a token can only happen on user interaction.**